# Truncate text from server with Java

Tags: java, regex, io

I'm receiving a message from my server like so:

```
/713.105.135.149:54969: [{"row 0":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]},{"row 1":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]},{"row 2":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]},{"row 3":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]},{"row 4":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]},{"row 5":[{"column 0":"WhitePawn"},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]},{"row 6":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]},{"row 7":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]}]
```

I'd like to encode it as JSON, so I need to truncate all the stuff that isn't JSON, i.e. I need to axe this text `/713.105.135.149:54969:`.

Maybe I can use regex to string replace everything before `[{"`?

Is it possible to do that? if so, how?

Comment: Will the preamble you want to discard ever include `"["`? If not, then you don't need to use a regular expression, just a simple `.indexOf` and a `.substring`.

Comment: no, it won't include that

Comment: what I want to keep is valud JSON, it it'll always start with `[{"`, anything before that is garbage and I want to get rid of it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a regular expression. You can just use

```
String s = "/713.105.135.149:54969: [{\"row 0\": ...";
String trimmed = s.substring(s.indexOf("["));
System.out.println(trimmed);  // [{"row 0": ...
```

Comment: the thing is, the server address can be different, does this work even if the exact ip address isn't the same?

Comment: 'cause my naive solution was this... `message.replaceAll("/713.105.135.149:54969: ", "");`, but thats too rigid

Comment: Yes, my solution should work. It simply removes everything before the first `"["`.

Comment: man, I'm still not able to cast my string to json using `new JSONObject(trimmed);`, would you be down to chat for like 5 miuntues?

Comment: isn't there a chat feature on this site

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797141/convert-string-of-valid-json-to-json-object-in-java-so-i-can-index-into-it