# Convert string of valid JSON to JSON object in Java, so I can index into it

Tags: java, json, serialization

I have this string:

```
[{"row 0":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]},{"row 1":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]},{"row 2":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]},{"row 3":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]},{"row 4":[{"column 0":"WhitePawn"},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]},{"row 5":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]},{"row 6":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]},{"row 7":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]}]
```

^ it's currently a String, let's call it `string`.

I'm trying to convert it into JSON like so:

```
new JSONObject(string);
```

but it isn't working. How to do this in Java?

Code looks like so:

```
    private void parseMessageRedrawBoard(String message) {

        Log.d("0000: ", message);

        String trimmed = message.substring(message.indexOf("["));

        Log.d("1111: ", trimmed);

        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        try {
            jsonObject = new JSONObject(trimmed);
            Log.d("maybe worked...", "~");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.d("dammit: ", e.getMessage());
        }

    }
```

Comment: How 'not working' ? share code, errors, ways for us to help you, remember that we're not next to you knowing all

Comment: [JSONLint](https://jsonlint.com/) says that it's valid JSON. Do you get an exception?

Comment: The JSON starts with a `[`, which means it's an array, not an object, so use `JSONArray` instead.

Comment: @Andreas ok, I accept that you downvoted it and it was honorable of you to tell me why

Comment: @Andreas that other dude gave the right answer though, but do you know how I would then index into it?

Comment: @s.matthew.english Yes, you use the methods available on the `JSONArray` object. **Read the documentation** to learn what methods are available.

Comment: @Andreas but tbh, `List<Map<String, Object>> jsonArray` isn't `JSON`, I feel like it needs to be of type `JSON` to use it like JSON, is that right?

Comment: @s.matthew.english What `List<Map<String, Object>> jsonArray`? There is no such type in the question code. I'm commenting on the code in the *question*. Replace `JSONObject jsonObject` with `JSONArray jsonArray`, and `jsonObject = new JSONObject(trimmed)` with `jsonArray = new JSONArray(trimmed)`, and the code will work fine.

Comment: @Andreas yeah, you're right, that worked

Comment: So exactly like I said in my first comment: **Use `JSONArray` instead**.

Comment: yeah, youre right. but the new question is can I do this... `JSONArray subArray = new JSONArray(jsonArray.get(4));`, and then this `subArray.get(0).toString()`, right now seems like no, 'casue I'm getting an error

Comment: @s.matthew.english **So create a new question**, showing the problem you have. *This* question has been solved. --- But, to get you started: Why are you doing `new JSONArray()` there? `jsonArray.get(4)` will return already-parsed JSON. Without knowing exactly which JSON library you're using *(you never said, so remember to say in your next Question)*, it's impossible to say which exact method to call to get the values you want.

Comment: @Andreas, how about this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797565/granular-indexing-into-json-sub-array-in-java-following-conversion-from-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trimming the string and turning it into an invalid JSON.

Your JSON starts with a "[" that indicates it is an array. If it starts with "{" you can assume that is an object.

So, as your JSON is an array, you can parse this exact content you mentioned with:

```
JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(string);
```

And access the elements like in a List:

```
jsonArray.get(0);
```

Comment: nice man, I think that worked, but now how can I index into it?

Comment: I tried this `jsonArray[1]` but it didn't work, I wanna grab that value `WhitePawn`

Comment: No need to switch JSON library to fix the problem.

Comment: @Andreas what are you talking about problem, I'm pretty sure that soliution worked

Comment: @s.matthew.english The problem is that question code is trying the parse a JSON *array* as a JSON *object*. Simply replacing `JSONObject` with `JSONArray` from the same JSON library will fix the problem. The answer given here will work too, but not because it's using a different library. It'll work because it asks for a `List` in return. As such, it's not a good answer, because it doesn't explain *why* the question code is wrong, and there is no need to switch JSON library.

Comment: @Andreas I feel like you know what youre doing, could you show me in an answer so I can see what your talking about in actual fact?

Comment: I can index into it after doing this `JSONArray data = new JSONArray(jsonArray);`, but only one layer in, I want to index two layers in, if you know what I mean

Comment: @s.matthew.english That is a different question. Now that you know how to parse the JSON without error, if you have trouble *using* the parsed JSON, you should create another Question, asking for help, showing what you've tried, and where you're stuck. Don't try to morph this question into something else. But, before creating a new question, do some **research**, because it's very likely that others have had the same problem, and the web already has the answers you're looking for.

Comment: @Andreas is right. I edited the answer. (But still recommend the Gson library)

Comment: yo guys, wanna take a stab at helping me with the next step... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797565/granular-indexing-into-json-sub-array-in-java-following-conversion-from-string