# Granular indexing into json sub-array in Java, following conversion from string

Tags: java, json, serialization, io

This journey starts with a message from a server, which becomes a string, initially it looks like this:

```
/713.105.135.149:54969: [{"row 0":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]},{"row 1":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]},{"row 2":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]},{"row 3":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]},{"row 4":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]},{"row 5":[{"column 0":"WhitePawn"},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]},{"row 6":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]},{"row 7":[{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]}]
```

then I truncate all the stuff that's not valid JSON like so `message.substring(message.indexOf("["));`

Following that I cast it as a JSONarray, using this code `JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(trimmed);`

Subsequently, I want to index into it, I can sort of do that like so `jsonArray.get(4);`

but this returns `{"row 4":[{"column 0":"WhitePawn"},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}]}`, whereas what I actually want is `WhitePawn`.

The problem is that `jsonArray.get(4)` gave me back only a `JSONObject`, whereas what I think I need/want is another `JSONArray`, so I can once again index into it, something like `JSONArray subArray = jsonArray.get(0);`, the trouble is, that doesn't work.

How can I make the result of `jsonArray.get(4)` return, or be cast to, something that I can again index into?

The full code looks like this:

```
    private void parseMessageRedrawBoard(String message) throws Exception {

        Log.d("0000: ", message);

        String trimmed = message.substring(message.indexOf("["));

        Log.d("1111: ", trimmed);

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(trimmed);

        //"column 0"

        Object subArray = jsonArray.get(4);

        Log.d("YES: ", subArray.toString());
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

spoiler alert, `JSONArray subArray = jsonArray.getJSONArray(4);` didn't work, so much for RTFM!

but this works...

```
    private void parseMessageRedrawBoard(String message) throws Exception {

        Log.d("0000: ", message);

        String trimmed = message.substring(message.indexOf("["));

        Log.d("1111: ", trimmed);

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(trimmed);

        //"column 0"

        JSONObject subObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(4);

        JSONArray result = subObject.getJSONArray("row 4");

        Log.d("YES: ", result.get(0).toString());
    }
```

thanks @Andreas for the tips!

Comment: Because the value in the outer array is a *JSON Object*, as indicated by the value starting with `{`, and you need to call `getJSONObject` instead. Perhaps you should [**learn JSON Syntax**](http://json.org/) *(yes, RTFM!)*, so you understand the data you're reading.

Comment: how then how to index into that newly minted `JSONObject`?

Comment: The data is an array of objects. The object has one dynamically named field, and the value of that field is an array of objects. --- Since the field is dynamically named, you need to iterate the fields. If you read the javadoc of `JSONObject` *(yes, another RTFM!)*, you'll find the methods for doing that.

Comment: maybe something like this... `JSONObject subObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(4);

            Object result = subObject.get("row 4");`

Comment: your a pretty great hacker, what do you do for work?

Comment: actually sort of... it gives me `{"column 0":"WhitePawn"}`, I thought `optString()` would do the trick, but it seems not

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52797787/get-only-value-from-jsonarray-i-e-without-also-the-key-in-java @Andreas, I know you like seperate questions, so... just made that guy