# Get only value from JSONArray, i.e. without also the key, in Java

Tags: java, json, serialization, io, deserialization

I'm looking for a way to return only the value after a call to `get()` on a particular index of a JSONArray.

Here'd the method I'm working with:

```
    private void parseMessageRedrawBoard(String message) throws Exception {

        Log.d("0000: ", message);

        String trimmed = message.substring(message.indexOf("["));

        Log.d("1111: ", trimmed);

        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(trimmed);

        //"column 0"

        JSONObject subObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(4);

        JSONArray result = subObject.getJSONArray("row 4");

        Log.d("YES: ", result.opt(0).toString());
    }
```

but that returns me this `{"column 0":"WhitePawn"}`

I've been looking at the docs for a method that would return me only `WhitePawn`, and after trying all of the reasonable looking methods on `JSONArray` it seems it doesn't have one.

What's the idiomatic java way to return only `WhitePawn`, without also  `{"column 0":"WhitePawn"}`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

May you can use `getJsonString()` to return only the value of specific key.

```
getJsonString(int index)
```

> Returns the string value at the specified position in this array.

[JsonArray Documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/JsonArray.html)